# Как перенести данные из console.log в json файл?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть скрипт, который выводит данные в console.log, как данные из console.log положить в отдельный файл json?

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.search({
 term: 'ninja',
 num: 2,
 page: 3,
 country : 'us',
 lang: 'lang'
 })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.search({
 term: 'ninja',
 num: 2,
 page: 3,
 country : 'us',
 lang: 'lang'
 })
  .then(response => {
  fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(response));
})
  .catch(err => {
  fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: Отлично, работает. Спасибо!